# VBA Macro- PivotTble Auto-Filter Combo-Box - CurretnPage Issue

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, pivot-table

I am creating a dashboard with multiple pivot tables and have run into a problem that I cant seem to overcome. I have a primary worksheet where all the data will be displayed with direct references to the pivots tables which reside on another worksheet. I am using a combobox to filter the data from the pivot tables. I have been able to get the VBA code working for the macro when I am on the worksheet containing the pivot tables, but I cant get it to work when I am on the primary page where the customer will actually choose the filter, as far as I can tell the issue resides with the .CurrentPage variable, I don't how I can change this to filter correctly. Below is the code I have, the combobox is on worksheet("Dashboard") while the PvtTbls are on Worksheet("Pivot Tables"). Can anyone guide me on how to get this working, I am tearing out my hair researching this the last 3 days with no luck.

```
Sub Year_Change()
'
' Year_Change Macro
'
    Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Termination Index").PivotFields("Year").CurrentPage = (Range("I1"))
    Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Quality Index Top").PivotFields("Year").CurrentPage = (Range("I1"))
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: to make it clear, does that exact code work when you are within `Worksheet("Pivot Tables")` and it doesn't when you are in `worksheet("Dashboard")`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, with the difference of the "target value" for the CurrentPage being a cell (i.e. Range("a1")) instead of a combobox. Adding ".value" worked for me.

```
Sub Year_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Pivottable1").PivotFields("Year").CurrentPage = (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
    Worksheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("Pivottable2").PivotFields("Year").CurrentPage = (ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

For your problem: could you elaborate on the combobox you are using? Is it a proper activeX-control or just a filter on admissible data in a cell?